# Symbolic package is not found by octave (4.0.0)

Tags: octave

I have installed python (2.7.8), sympy (0.7.5) and symbolic package (2.3.0) in Octave (4.0.0). In Octave I did

```
pkg install symbolic-2.3.0.tar (without errors)
pkg load symbolic (without errors)
```

And now I am trying to use it:

```
>> symbols
error: 'symbols' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

Windows 7, 64-bit. The package seems to be in the list of installed ones:

```
Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
--------------+---------+-----------------------
     control *|   3.0.0 | C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave\packages\control-3.0.0
   financial *|   0.5.0 | C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave\packages\financial-0.5.0
          io *|   2.4.1 | C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave\packages\io-2.4.1
       optim *|   1.5.1 | C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave\packages\optim-1.5.1
      signal *|   1.3.2 | C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave\packages\signal-1.3.2
     splines *|   1.2.9 | C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave\packages\splines-1.2.9
      struct *|  1.0.13 | C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave\packages\struct-1.0.13
    symbolic *|   2.3.0 | C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave\packages\symbolic-2.3.0
```

Why is the package not used? Would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not "symbols" in current  version of symbolic package. You can see example of code in [wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Symbolic_package). You can try use **syms** for testing of loading symbolic package:

```
>> syms x
```

Read documentation - [Octave-Forge](http://octave.sourceforge.net/symbolic/overview.html)

May be useful link - [symbolic-computation-and-octave](http://scidic.mechran.com/2010/09/symbolic-computation-and-octave.html)